# Retrieving class property/constant names from its value - Python

Tags: python, winapi

I am writing a script to get the details of all the scheduled tasks running on a host but the value returned from various functions like task.GetStatus() returns the an integer value that relates back to a property name in the taskscheduler module

So...

```
import win32api, pythoncom
from win32com.taskscheduler import taskscheduler
ts = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(taskscheduler.CLSID_CTaskScheduler,None,pythoncom.CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,taskscheduler.IID_ITaskScheduler)
task = ts.Activate('TestJob')
task.GetStatus()
```

returns a 267008 which relates to `SCHED_S_TASK_READY = 267008` or `taskscheduler.SCHED_S_TASK_READY` but how to I get to the property/constant name from its corresponding value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[i[0] for i in taskscheduler.__dict__.items() if i[1] == 267008]
```